# Why in this sentence is 「の」used in this fashion?

Tags: meaning, particle-の, questions

> 「今日は何する**の**？」

I found this sentence by a Japanese person on a Japanese speaking website.
I am aware that の is the possessive particle in Japanese, and allows for sentences such as

> 「僕**の**娘は店に行って靴を買います。」

But what I don't understand is why の is used at the end of the first sentence without directly stating anything. Why exactly is の being used like that, and what does it mean?

Comment: Related: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/15047/9749

Comment: Please see Blavius's link, and generally try to look for answers using the search tool before asking anything. It would save you a lot of time :)