# parsing of どうしたっての？

Tags: grammar

Context: an anime (Sword Art Online). A girl wakes up to find his travelling companion digging a hole in the snow-covered terrain. She proceeds to ask, どうしたっての？ The translation reads "What are you doing"?
I'd like some help to make sense of all the components.

I am familiar with どうした meaning "what's wrong", with っての as a shortening of と言うの, with -たって standing for -ても and with の used as a feminine version of んだ / んです. I don't seem to be able to piece it all together though...

Comment: Does this answer your question [Meaning of sentences ending in の](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/15047/45489)?

Comment: @sundowner thank you. That clarifies the final の but I'm still not sure how to interpret the rest... does どうした mean "what have you been doing?" ? Also, what about the function of って in the sentence?

Comment: Does it help it it is どうしたというの?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Practically you can think of どうしたというの/どうしたっていうの as a variant of どうしたの=*what is the matter/what happened*.

Looking at a definition of [という](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%A8%E8%A8%80%E3%81%86/#jn-154743), it can emphasize the preceding word, and どうしたっての has more questioning tone than どうしたの.

> ２ 「と」の受ける事柄を取り立てて強調する意を表す。

Comment: Got it, all clear now. Thank you.